# returning values with a where clause

Tags: linq, where-clause

I have two tables as follows:

```
 ScholarSubject
ScholarSubjectID<pk>
ScholarID
SubjectID
Mark
```

and

```
 AdmissionReq
SubjectID
DegreeCode
MinumumMark
```

I'm trying to return everything from a Degree table (with PK degreeID) where the mark for a scholar is less than the minimum mark for admissions. My query is as follows:

```
public List<object> getDegreeByAPSandRequirements()
    {
        using (DataLayer.CareerDatabaseEntities context = new DataLayer.CareerDatabaseEntities())
        {
            return (from Degrees in context.Degrees
                    join admissions in context.AdmissionReqs on
                    Degrees.DegreeCode equals admissions.DegreeCode
                    join subject in context.Subjects on
                    admissions.SubjectID equals subject.SubjectID
                    join scholarsubject in context.ScholarSubjects on
                    subject.SubjectID equals scholarsubject.SubjectID
                    join scholar in context.Scholars on
                    scholarsubject.ScholarID equals scholar.ScholarID
                    where Degrees.APSScore <= scholar.APSScore && admissions.MinimumMark <= scholarsubject.NSC && scholarsubject.SubjectID.Equals(admissions.SubjectID)
                    select Degrees).Distinct().ToList<object>();

        }
    }
```

Everything works, except if I change one of the marks (in ScholarSubject) to a lesser value than the minumum mark (in AdmissionsReq) then it still returns a degree. I want to return a degree if both marks are greater than the minimum requirements and not only one of the marks.

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please help me??

Comment: Try to look what you will have if remove 'where', is there will be all what you expected?

Comment: 1. do you want those degrees where the scholar's values are LESS than the minimum or where the minimum is less than scholar's values ? 2. you return just degrees - are they in any way distinct across scholars ? Or can a degree be assigned to multiple scholars/subjects ? If so, even if in one example you would not return the degree, you can have another one where this same degree is valid.

Comment: I'd like to have where the scholar's mark is greater than the minimum, so I have changed admissions.MinimumMark <= scholarsubject.NSC to scholarsubject.NSC >= admissions.MinimumMark, but that only checks if one of the two marks (in ScholarSubject) and not if both match the minimum mark. I just return degrees for one scholar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure I understand what you're trying to do - unless you have just one scholar in your database it seems to me you will return a list of all degrees achieved by all scholars. If you don't want this, you need to filter on scholarID in the `where` clause.

But anyway - in order to get more information I would try to do 2 things.

1. I would change your query and start it with the `scholar` not with the `degree` as this might avoid some duplicates:

   ```
       from scholar in context.Scholars 
       join scholarsubject in context.ScholarSubjects on scholar.ScholarID equals scholarsubject.ScholarID
       join subject in context.Subjects on scholarsubject.SubjectID equals subject.SubjectID
       join admission in context.AdmissionReqs on subject.SubjectID equals admission.SubjectID
       join degree in context.Degrees on admission.DegreeCode equals degree.DegreeCode
       where degree.APSScore <= scholar.APSScore 
           && admission.MinimumMark <= scholarsubject.NSC 
         //&& scholarsubject.SubjectID.Equals(admission.SubjectID) // you should not need this line as you have the joins in place to assert this
       select degree)
      .Distinct()
      .ToList<object>();
   ```
2. If this produces the same result as your previous query, then I'd change the return type to see what exactly you are getting - replace the last line with this and inspect the collection:

   ```
    select new {ScholarID = scholar.ScholarID, Degree = degree})
      .Distinct()
      .ToList();
   ```

Comment: Everything works, but I see my problem is with the scholarsubject.SubjectID.Equals(admission.SubjectID) check. I want to check that, for ALL of the SubjectID's in scholarsubject, that match admission SubjectID, check admission marks and aps score. I had my where statement as: "where Degrees.APSScore <= scholar.APSScore && admissions.MinimumMark <= scholarsubject.NSC && admissions.SubjectID == 1 && admissions.SubjectID == 21", but it only works if I remove the second admissions.SubjectID check. Is there a way to put all the ids in a list & check if the admissions match all the ids in that list?

Comment: To simplify it, I want to check if it matches both subjectID’s (so checking a combination of id’s). Sure a list method does that, but not sure. Everything else works fine, just checking a combination of those subjectID's and not just one subjectID. IS there a list method to do that?

Comment: @user1397978 - I'm confused - you are joining on the SubjectID which means that you're going to get a separate result for each subject ID. In this case I don't see how this would ever evaluate to true `admissions.SubjectID == 1 && admissions.SubjectID == 21` - the subjectID will be either 1 or 21. Unless you want to group the results for a scholar and evaluate the group ? I.e. return a degree if for ALL subjectIDs the minimum has been achieved ?